# Community Builder Self Register Apex Controller

Tags: apex, customer-portal, lightning-community, identity

I am using a customer community self register builder for a Napili Template page and I'm wondering where the controller is for custom login.  I am the administrator and have access to the community builder.  I've modified the CommunitiesSelfRegController but it's only impacting the visualforce page and not the community builder Register page.

[Here's a link to "custom code for lightning login pages"](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_custom_login_self_reg_lightning.htm&type=5)

[Self Register Screenshot](https://res.cloudinary.com/hy4kyit2a/image/upload/doc/trailhead/en-usde1cf9b697b4d9460b9a9340bdd3eab9.png)

[Here's the trailhead for that unit](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/identity_external/units/identity_external_registration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you install Napili template, these are the custom Lightning component that are added to your org. [image][image]

If you open any of these components on Developer console, you should see a commented tag:

```
 Line 1: <!-- add implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" to surface the component in community builder -->
 For SelfRegister form component:
 Line 2: <aura:component controller="LightningSelfRegisterController"> 
 For Login form component:
 Line 2: <aura:component controller="LightningLoginFormController">
```

May be one of your team members already added the **implements** attribute to the components, therefore they are available for using on the Community pages.

So you should be editing: **LightningLoginFormController** or **LightningSelfRegisterController** to make changes that to reflect on the components of the community pages.

1. [Salesforce
   Reference](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_custom_login_self_reg_lightning.htm&type=5)
2. [Salesforce documentation (page
   117)](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/204/16/en-us/sfdc/pdf/community_templates.pdf)

Comment: actually the issue was that the components didn't install on my original Napili build (perhaps it predated these components).  I installed a dummy Napili community and it installed these components!

Comment: I didn't get these components installed with the Health Cloud Template I am supposed to be using but I still need these. Any idea how to enable their creation?